# How to update android database when fresh JSON content arieves?

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, refresh

Could someone suggest me a way on how to update my apps SQLite database when the content of the parsed JSON file is changed?

I am having a hard time finding the right solution, now I have to clear the cache before the app starts, but the end user obviously won't do that.

I asume changing the table version is not suitable for frequent updates (hourly).

Thanks!

Comment: "when the content of the parsed JSON file is changed" - are you polling via http periodically? Can't you just update then?

Comment: @KenWolf - yes, I return the json via HTTPclient (loopj.lib). But what to call for updating the database? I have checked the dev documentation too, but so far have no clue...thanks

Comment: Here's how you update an sqlite db: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow

Comment: @KenWolf - thanks really much, I take a closer look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KenWolf mentioned [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow) documentation in the comments.

> Update a Database:

When you need to modify a subset of your database values, use the `update()` method.

Updating the table combines the content values syntax of `insert()` with the ***where*** syntax of `delete()`.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// New value for one column
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);

// Which row to update, based on the title
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "MyTitle" };

int count = db.update(
    FeedReaderDbHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
    values,
    selection,
    selectionArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your **database version** by incrementing by 1 from  current value.

It will make possible of updation.

Comment: but is it ok to increment the database version each time the app starts? Because I need to update the app frequently.